# Find and Replace String with colons, double quotes and spaces in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using a `Get-Content -Replace` to find and Replace a string which looks like below :

From :
"Folder": "AAAAAA",

To :

"Folder": "BBBBBB",

AAAAAA and BBBBBBB will be variables `row.CurrentFolder` and `row.NewFolder`

I have tried many combinations, but none work and I am having issues escaping the ":" or it could be the space. I am not sure.

Error : Unexpected token ':' in expression or statement.

Tried these :

```
((Get-Content "$($outputdir)\$($row.NewFolder).$outputext" -Raw) -Replace "$($row.CurrentFolder)","$($row.NewFolder)") | Set-Content "$($outputdir)\$($row.NewFolder).$outputext"
```

This has the flaw that it will replace all instances of row.CurrentFolder

Please suggest

Comment: It would help if you edited the question and showed a few lines of the input file and what the desired output would be.

Comment: Does [**this**](https://tio.run/##nVHBTsMwDL3nK6yoh1Wi/QMkYGiIy0Bs4rRL1Jo1kC4hdWgn4NuLl8K6oYkDVmQpfrbfe4mzLfqmQmP6fo5tdktYQ8zLrUO41h4Lsn4L2VzVCPIukAskxYnemTYI2b2iCmS@GhpXVzFy6nhmgZRN7YZwQ3/1QfaoTGCuZaUb4NNYZm5U7Xg/YUf5ZYwdpOA16OIFnmwHVCmC51C7BrxeVwT2DT1XEb77S7uWQiQ2MpbawzkLkD8FXrwrRKWJty1fLt4FcEyD96x5Zk2JcWjYJyPIDzECgwspPoWY3By4lclkpE1/eR752fqDalPO6IwqMM6xlPxIQSrP9sCePZXwAYt/UApxKPTEf/T9Fw) help?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could help you.

To replace a specific instance of the string "Folder": "AAAAAA", with "Folder": "BBBBBB", you need to be careful with the escaping of special characters in PowerShell. Here is an example of how you can achieve this:

```
# Read the content of the file and replace the string
$content = Get-Content "$($outputdir)\$($row.NewFolder).$outputext" -Raw
$newContent = $content -replace ('"Folder": "{0}",' -f [regex]::Escape($row.CurrentFolder)), ('"Folder": "{0}",' -f $row.NewFolder)

# Write the updated content back to the file
$newContent | Set-Content "$($outputdir)\$($row.NewFolder).$outputext"
```

In this script, the `-f` operator is used for string formatting, and the `[regex]::Escape` method is used to escape any special characters in the string. This way, the replacement process should work correctly without issues related to special characters. Make sure to replace the file path and file extension variables with your actual values.